# Is it possible to use pytest-bdd with SeleniumBase?

Tags: python, selenium, pytest-bdd, seleniumbase

This is how I would write a SeleniumBase/pytest-bdd test:

*ddg.feature*:

```
Feature: Browse DuckDuckGo

    Going to DuckDuckGo webpage.

    Scenario: I can see the title
        When I go to DuckDuckGo webpage
        Then Duck is present in the title
```

*test_ddg.py*:

```py
from seleniumbase import BaseCase
from pytest_bdd import scenarios, when, then

scenarios("./ddg.feature")

class MyTestClass(BaseCase):

@when("I go to DuckDuckGo webpage")
def go_to_ddg(self):
    self.open('https://duckduckgo.com/')

@then("Duck is present in the title")
def is_title_present(self):
    assert 'Duck' in self.get_title()
```

However, this is not working. *scenarios()* function cannot see the *when* and *then* descriptors.

Any idea how to make this work, if it is possible ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use SeleniumBase as a `pytest` fixture, rather than inheriting BaseCase directly. See "The sb `pytest` fixture" section at

- https://seleniumbase.io/help_docs/syntax_formats/ or
  this answer:
- https://gitter.im/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase?at=5dc421f9e469ef4358dc918e

So - in your example -  you do not need to import `BaseCase`, and you should use "sb" instead of "self"

another example: features/homepage.feature

```
@homepage
Feature: Homepage

  Scenario: Homepage this and that
    Given the browser is at the homepage
    When the user clicks this
    Then that is shown
```

step_defs/homepage_test.py

```
from pytest_bdd import scenarios, given, when then
from .pom import *

# Constants
PAGE = 'https://seleniumbase.io'

# Scenarios 
scenarios('../features/homepage.feature')

# Given Steps
@given('the browser is at the homepage')
def the_browser_is_at_the_homepage(sb):
    """the browser is at the homepage."""
    sb.get(PAGE)

# When Steps
@when('the user clicks this')
def the_user_clicks_this(sb):
    """the user clicks this."""
    sb.click(Menu.this)

# Then Steps
@then('that is shown')
def that_is_shown(sb):
    """that is shown."""
    sb.assert_text('The sb pytest fixture',SyntaxPage.that)
```

step_defs/pom.py

```
class Menu():  
    this = "//nav//a[contains(text(),'Syntax Formats')]"

class SyntaxPage():
    that = "(//h3)[4]"
```